# Can I call a Javascript function from a coffeescript file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I'm trying to call a javascript function from a Coffeescript file, for my `$(document).ready()` and it's never getting called.

The function I want to call comes from an external source that I have included in my html head element, just before the include of my coffeescript file, like this:

```
<script src="external.js"></script>
<%= javascript_include_tag params[:controller], 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

and in my coffeescript file (called someControllerName.coffee) I do this:

```
ready = ->
  ... call my method

$ -> ready
```

Is this the correct way? I can see in Chrome that my script is compile to javascript, and I can see it in the Network tab of the inspector.

I'm using Rails 4, and this is my application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

edit:

If I replace my method call by `alert("...");` it works, and if I call my javascript method using javascript in `$(document).ready()` it works fine.

edit2:

Here's my real javascript function:

```
var ready = function () {
  $('pre code').each(function (i, e) {
      hljs.highlightBlock(e)
  });
};

$(document).ready(ready);
```

**I solved the problem doing this:**

```
highlight = ->
  $("pre code").each (i, e) ->
    hljs.highlightBlock(e)

$(document).on 'ready page:load', ->
  highlight()
```

Comment: I reckon its probably your function within the coffeescript file?  If alert works but not a method call it might be your method

Comment: I added my real javascript function, could you tell me how you would implement it in coffeescript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't do what you think it does:

```
$ -> ready
```

In JavaScript that is:

```
$(function() {
    return ready;
});
```

Your problem is that just `ready` is simply a reference to the function, it is not a function call like it would be in Ruby. You'd have to say `ready()` to call the function, the function calling parentheses are only optional when you're calling a function with arguments: `f x` and `f(x)` are the same but `f` and `f()` are different.

I think you want to say:

```
$ -> ready()
```

or even:

```
$ ready # same as $(ready)
```

Comment: Thank you, now my function gets called, but it doesn't compile because of errors. I have included in my original post my real javascript function, if you could help me figuring out  how to implement it in coffeescript.

Comment: You got this figure out while I was away, right? You should be able to say just `$(document).on 'ready page:load', ready` too.